# Laravel redirect dynamic subdomains to folder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I creating CMS with function auto-creating subdomains

Example: user pressing button **Create domain** I adding subdomain name **john** to DB and creating folder **domain.com/subdomains/john.domain.com** now i need redirect this subdomain **john.domain.com** to directory **domain.com/subdomains/john.domain.com**

code web.php:

```
if (!function_exists('getSubDomain')) {
    function getSubDomain($url)
    {
        $domain = $url = str_replace(Request::getRequestUri(),'', $url);
        $url = str_replace('http:','',$url);
        $url = str_replace('//','',$url);
        $url = str_replace('www.','',$url);
        $url = str_replace('domain.com','',$url);
        $url = rtrim($url,'.');
        $url = ltrim($url,'.');
        if($url){
            $user = ['john','barry','wells','cisco'];
            if(isset(array_flip($user)[$url])){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.domain.com'], function(){
    if(getSubDomain(Request::url())){

        //Here need redirect to folder.

        echo "Subdomain";
        exit;
    }
});
```

Comment: Needs more information. What exactly is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect to directory? Is the "directory" a part of your laravel app? What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: I added more info